# Tensorflow error when trying to train model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Error while running `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir = training / --pipeline_config_path = training / faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

```
    \trainer.py:260: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "D:\Studies\Python Scripts\Test\trainer.py", line 274, in train
    train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
  File "D:\Studies\Python Scripts\Test\trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue
    tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
  File "train.py", line 120, in get_next
    return dataset_util.make_initializable_iterator(
```

Following : https://github.com/satendrapandeymp/object_detection
I have successfully managed to implement object detection api test using webcam, but now this is upon training model these error keeps coming up one after another

Yet, another error from Python native cmd run.

```
 python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir = training / --pipeline_config_path = training / faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 93, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 93, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: = : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

Conda Environment run

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir = training / --pipeline_config_path = training / faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 93, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 93, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: = : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell without seeing the code, but it seems that there is some problem with the file `FLAGS.pipeline_config_path` and Windows fails to find the file, or doesn't have permissions to read it.

Maybe it is because when you set the value of the argument like `training / faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config` you are using spaces before and after `"/"`.

It seems that this is an issue that has been reported in Tensorflow's Github, maybe you can find a solution [in this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2215).

Comment: i tried running it `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config` then same issue so launched it from an elevated prompt and it throws the error  `return dataset_util.make_initializable_iterator(
AttributeError: module 'object_detection.utils.dataset_util' has no attribute 'make_initializable_iterator' `

Comment: Then it seems that there is a problem with `dataset_util` because it doesn't have the attribute `make_initializable_iterator` that you need. Maybe you are using and older version of the library.

Comment: Errors keeps on coming up, and there does not seems to be an updated model training tutorial which i can try. This type of classification does work some how where i can put in different images in different folders and it will give a frozen graph at the end of training : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXpsAiSajE0